# How do I place two tables with different numbers of rows at the same height?

Tags: tables

I want to start two tables with different number of rows at the same height. [image]

Basically, I want the horizontal lines to be at the same height.

This is the current code I have:

```
\adjustbox{valign=h}{
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c c } 
     NFA & 0 & 1 \\ 
     \hline
     $q_0$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $q_0$ \\ 
     $q_1$ & $\varnothing$ & $q_2$ \\
     $q_2$ & $q_3$ & $q_3$ \\
     $q_3$ & $\varnothing$ & $\varnothing$ \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c c } 
     DFA & 0 & 1 \\ 
     \hline
     $q_0$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $q_0$ \\ 
     $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_2]$ \\
     $[q_0q_2]$ & $[q_0q_1q_3]$ & $[q_0q_3]$ \\
     $[q_0q_1q_3]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_2]$ \\ 
     $[q_0q_3]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
```

Comment: What's `\adjustbox` supposed to do? And `valign=h` is not a valid option.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the optional argument `[t]` to each `tabular` they will be vertically aligned by the first line.

As egreg mentions in a comment, the `\adjustbox` likely doesn't have any effect, and `valign=h` is not a valid option for it anyway, so I removed it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c c } 
     NFA & 0 & 1 \\ 
     \hline
     $q_0$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $q_0$ \\ 
     $q_1$ & $\varnothing$ & $q_2$ \\
     $q_2$ & $q_3$ & $q_3$ \\
     $q_3$ & $\varnothing$ & $\varnothing$ \\ 
    \end{tabular}%
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c c } 
     DFA & 0 & 1 \\ 
     \hline
     $q_0$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $q_0$ \\ 
     $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_2]$ \\
     $[q_0q_2]$ & $[q_0q_1q_3]$ & $[q_0q_3]$ \\
     $[q_0q_1q_3]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_2]$ \\ 
     $[q_0q_3]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ & $[q_0q_1]$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `\adjustbox` has any influence on the output (apart adding unwanted spaces at either end, because of missing `%`). By the way, `valign=h` doesn't seem to be a valid option.

Comment: @egreg I considered removing it, but I didn't know the context, so I left it. You are of course correct about `h`, so that's another argument for removing it altogether. Will edit, thanks.

Comment: You could also add a `%` in the line before `\quad`. ;-)